# Array to CSV to file

Tags: php, arrays, csv, export-to-csv

I'm creating a CSV from an array. The problem is that I dont want to download it but I want to save it to a folder in my server. This is my function

```
    protected function array_to_csv_download($array, $filename = "export.csv", $delimiter=";") {
    header('Content-Type: application/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachement; filename="'.$filename.'";');

       $f = fopen('php://output', 'w');

    foreach ($array as $line) {
        fputcsv($f, $line, $delimiter); 
    }
}
```

How can I make it so that it saves it to the server? Thanks!

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: Remove the headers and use a file path instead of `php://output`. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Comment: Rather than send to the standard output, open a file with your `fopen` function call.

Comment: so why was it voted down? Can you give some input so I can fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Remove headers.
2. Use you server's file path in fopen handle.

```
$f = fopen('path of file on server ', 'w');
```